# ASP.NET Forms Authentication integrate with SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, active-directory, forms-authentication

I have a follow scenario:

SERVER 1 - IIS6
ASP.NET Web Application with Forms Authentication on Active Directory

SERVER 2 - SQL SERVER
Database

How i can integrate the security of Forms Authentication AD with SQL Server?

My objective is use Forms AD authentication and integrate the user authenticated for get data profile.

Ex: 
`SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [TABLE].[USER] = SYSTEM_USER`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

> User.Identity.Name

to get the username of the currently logged in user and pass that via a parameter to the database query that you use.

Comment: OK, there is a way to integrate the authentication? Without pass parameters.

For example, in SQL Server will SYSTEM_USER is the authenticated user in AD.

Answer (score 1):

You should confire your application for SQL Membership provider. Some information here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197472(office.12).aspx